# How to find a Facebook user page by an app user id

Tags: facebook

I can get my second user id by using my mobile app via Facebook SDK.

If I told my second user id to an other Facebook user who uses same mobile app,
can he/she find my Facebook page by using it?

I found out the way to access to my Facebook page.
That is to launch a browser app and fill in the following URL.
`http://facebook.com/{ID}`

But, I could not find out other way.
I want to find the better way.

Comment: Facebook page linked with the Facebook App, right ?

Comment: It is better, or else launch browser app. Thanks.